# UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION in android studio

Tags: android, parse-platform

I was trying to code a simple android app and i get this error message.Please help

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       D:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\user\Desktop\SocialNetworking\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\user\Desktop\SocialNetworking\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

My gradle build is as follows

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "jason.orchid.com.socialnetworking"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have included `'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:x.x'`  twice in your dependencies. Remove any one of them and the problem will be resolved.